# How to install Linux on the Lego Mindstorms NXT

Tags: linux, system-installation, embedded

Has anybody ever successfully installed Linux on the Lego Mindstorms NXT Intelligent Brick? I've found plenty of things on Google, but none of them worked.
I can't find the download for legOS, and the gcc I was told to download never actually built (although it spent over 5 minutes in an install script). There was no download page for NXC (Not Exactly C).
NOTE: I have an Ubuntu Linux system, a Mac OSX Lion system, and access to Windows (although I would prefer to avoid Windows).

Comment: Please describe "doesn't work", and what exactly you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFIAK, only the new Mindstorms EV3 run Linux-based firmware. NXC is only a language and compiler for the Mindstorms NXT, and legOS is an alternative firmware.